# Flask API fails to return the value of queue - queue.get()

Tags: python, rest, flask, python-requests, queue

I am trying to append all my response in an queue under one end point and on other hand im trying to get only one result using another endpoint. But while using second endpoint I get failed as response. what would be the better approach ? Thanks in advance

```
import requests
import json
import queue

q_sample = queue.Queue()

@app.route('/try',methods=['GET'])
def getschedule():
    x = requests.get("https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/620012",verify=False)
    j_data = json.loads(x.content)
    for n in j_data:
      y = n['PostOffice']
      for x in y:
        q_sample.put(x)
    return jsonify({"size":q_sample.qsize()})

@app.route('/oneschedule',methods=['GET'])
def oneschedule():
    if not q_sample.empty():
        return jsonify({"schedule":q_sample.get(False)})
    else:
        return "Failed"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. How are you running the flask app?

Answer (score 0):

The issue that is you need to declare `q_sample` as global in the functions where you modify it, by adding the line `global q_sample` inside:

```
import requests
import json
import queue

q_sample = queue.Queue()

@app.route('/try',methods=['GET'])
def getschedule():
    global q_sample  # <--- declare q_sample global here
    x = requests.get("https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/620012",verify=False)
    j_data = json.loads(x.content)
    for n in j_data:
      y = n['PostOffice']
      for x in y:
        q_sample.put(x)
    return jsonify({"size":q_sample.qsize()})

@app.route('/oneschedule',methods=['GET'])
def oneschedule():
    global q_sample  # <--- declare q_sample global here too
    if not q_sample.empty():
        return jsonify({"schedule":q_sample.get(False)})
    else:
        return "Failed"
```